# $A^2=cA$ for some $c \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $0 \neq c \in \mathbb{C}$ a given constant. Suppose that $A$ has the following property:

$$A^2 = cA.$$

**Questions.**

1) Is there a matrix class for matrices those have this special property? If there is what is the name of it?

2) It is true or not, that $A$ has rank $1$. If it is prove it, if not give a counterexample.

3) Anything interesting about $A$?

Comment: If $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $u$ is also an eigenvector of $A^2$ with eigenvalue $c\lambda$.

Comment: If $A$ is regular $A$ must be diagonal with $A=cI$, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A^2=cA,\; c\ne0$ then the polynomial with simple roots $x^2-cx=x(x-c)$ annihilates $A$ so it's a diagonalizable matrix and it's similar to

$$\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{c,\cdots,c}_{r\;\text{times}},0,\cdots,0)=c\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\cdots,1}_{r\;\text{times}},0,\cdots,0)=cJ_r$$
so $A$ is similar to $cJ_r$ which's the matrix of $cP_V$: composition of an homothetie with a projection onto the image of $A$.

Comment: And here $r$ is the rank of $A$?

Comment: Yes!${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

The zero matrix satisfies $A^2 = cA$. As mentioned above, if $A$ is invertible then $A = cI$. Thus $A$ need not have rank $1$.

Otherwise, since $c \ne 0$, $(\frac{1}{c}A)^2 = \frac{1}{c}A$, so $\frac{1}{c}A$ is idempotent, hence is a projection onto $\text{im}(\frac{1}{c}A) = \text{im}(A)$, a proper nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Thus such matrices $A$ are precisely scalar multiples of a projection matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The identity matrix $I$ works with $c=1$.  And the matrix $aI$ works with $c=a$.  These are examples with rank $n$.  You could get a matrix of any rank $k$ with $1\le k<n$ by taking a matrix with $1$s in the first $k$ diagonal entries and $0$s everywhere else (both lower in the diagonal and in the off-diagonal).