# If $p(x)=x^2-cx$ annihilates $A$, then $A$ is similar to $c \operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $0 \neq c \in \mathbb{C}$ a given constant. Suppose that $A$ has the following property: $A^2 =cA$.

I had a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913415/a2-ca-for-some-c-neq-0) about this matrices, and I get an [anwser](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/913465/153012), which says the following.

> Since $A^2=cA,\; c\ne0$ then the polynomial with simple roots
>   $p(x)=x^2-cx=x(x-c)$ annihilates $A$ so it's a diagonalizable matrix and
>   it's similar to
>
> $$\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{c,\cdots,c}_{r\;\text{times}},0,\cdots,0)=c\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1,\cdots,1}_{r\;\text{times}},0,\cdots,0),$$
>   where $r$ is the rank of $A$.

**Question.** Can anybody prove this statment?

I don't know a lot about annihilator polynomials. The only thing I know, that the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) divides each of them.

**Question.** Anything else interesting about annihilator polynomials? Some paper, book,  wiki article, blog post which write about them?

Comment: Instead of proving it, you may benefit by reading about Normal Forms (especially Jordan Canonical Forms and when is a Jordan normal form of a matrix diagonal).

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is diagonalizable since its minimal polynomial is the product of *different* linear factors.

From here, it's clear that on the main diagonal of the diagonal matrix similar to $\;A\;$ we're going to have only $\;0's\;\;\text{and}\;\;c's\;$, but since each zero on the diagonal is one full row of zeros, and since similar matrices have the same rank, it is clear that there **must be** as many $\;c's\;$ on the diagonal as rk$\,A\;$ , and we're done.

Comment: Well, the other case is trivial, since the minimal pol. of $\;A\;$ must divide $\;x(x-c)\;$ , so if the min. pol. is $\;x\;$ then  $\;A=0\;,\;\;\text{rk}\;A=0\;$ , and if the min. pol. is $\;x-c\;$ , then $\;A=cI\;,\;\;\text{rk}\;A=n\;$. Both these cases are easy to deal with and, *anyway*, the matrix is diagonalizable.